# Can't read property when adding event listener

Tags: javascript

Been messing around with this for a while now, and it isn't making sense... Below is my `form` code, all I want to do is add an event listener for when that form is submitted.

```
<form action="php/submitMessage.php" method="post" id="messageForm" class="messageForm">
    <div class="left half">
        <input class="text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="First and Second Name *" 
        rules="[A-Za-z]*\s[A-Za-z]*" />
        <input class="text" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address *" 
        rules="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$" />

        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here... *" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="right half">
        <input class="text" type="text" name="reg" placeholder="Car Registration"/>

        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" style="display:none;" />

        <label for="image" id="reviewUpload" class="uploadBtn">Upload Image</label>

        <h8>Message will be regarded as a quote request if you provide an image.</h8>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcqfAwTAAAAAGLRx1Gea3JtHqWHO6s1RzO-HlZ2"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" style="background-color:#fff;color:#000;" 
    value="Submit Message/Quote" />
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
//Event Listeners
var messageForm = document.querySelector("messageForm");
messageForm.addEventListener("submit",handleSubmit);
```

I have even tried `document.getElementById` but that doesn't work either, I just keep on getting the following error, but I see no issue with the code at all!...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Edit:
Here is what I did to get it working:

```
window.onload = function () 
{ 
    //Event Listeners
    var messageForm = document.getElementById("messageForm");
    messageForm.addEventListener("submit",handleSubmit);
}
```

Comment: Change line

`var messageForm = document.querySelector("messageForm");`
to

`var messageForm = document.querySelector("#messageForm");`

Comment: if you use querySelector you have to define the CSS type "#" for ID and '." for class :) 
That should fix it

Comment: Simply replacing `document.querySelector` with `document.getElementById` would work, provided your JS code is executed after your `#messageForm` element is rendered in the DOM.

Comment: @Adam That must be where it is going wrong then, obviously the form is in the body, and the JavaScript is in the head. Should I make a function with my eventListener's to execute when the page has finished loading?

Comment: @MartynBall Put your JavaScript in the footer (right before the closing body tag). That way all `DOM` elements are ready when you try to access them. Your `document.querySelector` would work, but you need to add a `#` so it's `document.querySelector('#messageForm")` as pointed out by @Ginden

Comment: @Adam, want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you put your JavaScript in the footer (right before the closing body tag). That way all DOM elements are ready when you try to access them. Your `document.querySelector` would work, but you need to add a `#` so it's `document.querySelector('#messageForm")`